# Iterating through json request with multiple objects - django

Tags: python, json, django

I have a django project that I am working on. I have a api request that is returning a json response. With the json reponse that I am getting, there is a list of funding sources and within each funding source is an item that has the name with the object. I want to go though each json item and grab the names from the list of objewcts. how can I do this with the following response. I will also attach the request code that I sent...

response:

```
{  
   'funding-sources':[  
      {  
         '_links':{  
            'self':{  
               'href':'https://api-sandbox.dwolla.com/funding-sources/..546a9720a01',
               'type':'application/vnd.dwolla.v1.hal+json',
               'resource-type':'funding-source'
            },
            'customer':{  
               'href':'https://api-sandbox.dwolla.com/customers/..524dde5a',
               'type':'application/vnd.dwolla.v1.hal+json',
               'resource-type':'customer'
            },
            'initiate-micro-deposits':{  
               'href':'https://api-sandbox.dwolla.com/funding-sources/..6a9720a01/micro-deposits',
               'type':'application/vnd.dwolla.v1.hal+json',
               'resource-type':'micro-deposits'
            }
         },
         'id':'56b3ab2c-da7b-4edc-83a8-5546a9720a01',
         'status':'unverified',
         'type':'bank',
         'bankAccountType':'checking',
         'name':'Cheese',
         'created':'2017-11-02T05:37:39.000Z',
         'removed':False,
         'channels':[  
            'ach'
         ],
         'bankName':'SANDBOX TEST BANK',
         'fingerprint':'..ff1d7dcd22'
      },
      {  
         '_links':{  
            'self':{  
               'href':'https://api-sandbox.dwolla.com/funding-sources/..a51126e4',
               'type':'application/vnd.dwolla.v1.hal+json',
               'resource-type':'funding-source'
            },
            'customer':{  
               'href':'https://api-sandbox.dwolla.com/customers/..6b56524dde5a',
               'type':'application/vnd.dwolla.v1.hal+json',
               'resource-type':'customer'
            },
            'with-available-balance':{  
               'href':'https://api-sandbox.dwolla.com/funding-sources/..d3a51126e4',
               'type':'application/vnd.dwolla.v1.hal+json',
               'resource-type':'funding-source'
            },
            'balance':{  
               'href':'https://api-sandbox.dwolla.com/funding-sources/..6e4/balance',
               'type':'application/vnd.dwolla.v1.hal+json',
               'resource-type':'balance'
            }
         },
         'id':'522d3f3c-5ea2-4751-a485-4ad3a51126e4',
         'status':'verified',
         'type':'balance',
         'name':'Balance',
         'created':'2017-11-02T01:51:27.000Z',
         'removed':False,
         'channels':[  

         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

here is the code that I have right now for the request... the funding sources is in the -embedded objects as you will see in the code below:

```
sources = app_token.get('%s/funding-sources' % account_url)
accounts = sources.body['_embedded']
```

Comment: https://repl.it/Nc0A/0

Comment: for i in data['funding-sources']: print i['name']